# DataGridView Alignment

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview that gets its properties in a database. My problem is how will I set like DataGridViewContentAlignment.variable? Where variable is either MiddleRight, MiddleCenter etc etc.

This is the code for datagridview alignment:
`dgv.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;`

And I want something like this:

```
dgv.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MyVariable;
```

Comment: Like this: `DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[0, 0];
            DataGridViewContentAlignment dca = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
            cell.Style.Alignment = dca;` ,.. etc...?

Comment: Thanks, but my question is changing the alignment into variable. In your code I want to change the BottomCenter into a variable.

Comment: In my code the variable is called `dca`. Do look into [`enumerations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) !!

Comment: dca in your code sets to DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter, how can i can do so that BottomCenter a dynamic value. I am getting the value from Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataGridViewContentAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcontentalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  is an [enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

To store an enum value e.g. in a DMBS you can cast it to `int` and back.

Example:

```
DataGridViewContentAlignment dca1 = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

int dcai = (int)dca1;  // 32

DataGridViewContentAlignment dca2 = (DataGridViewContentAlignment)dcai;
```

Comment: Thank TaW! works great. I am saving the value as int in my database. I used the following and its works great. DataGridViewContentAlignment dca2 = (DataGridViewContentAlignment)dcai;